# How do I apply a fill modifier to a SwiftUI rectangle with a conditional gradient using the ternary operator

Tags: swiftui, gradient, modifier

**I want to apply a colour to a rectangle (or anything else) with a conditional gradient**

like this:

```
Rectangle().fill(useGradient ? .red.gradient : .red)
```

But this gives the following errors:

- *Member 'red' in 'AnyGradient' produces result of type 'Color', but
  context expects 'AnyGradient'*
- *Static property 'red' requires the types 'AnyGradient' and 'Color' be
  equivalent*

I could create two views and conditionally show either one but that seems like duplicating code.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

**Sample Code (Xcode 14.0, iOS 16.0)**

```
struct TestGradientView: View {
    
    var useGradient = false
    
    var body: some View {

        Rectangle()
            .fill(useGradient ? .red.gradient : .red)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 440, alignment: .center)
            

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Swift ternary operator `?:` requires both results to have the same type.  Use the `AnyShapeStyle()` type eraser to unite the types:

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(useGradient ? AnyShapeStyle(.red.gradient) : AnyShapeStyle(.red))
    .frame(width: 300, height: 440, alignment: .center)
```